ErrImagePull on Kubernetes 1.28 when pulling from a private registry with HTTP
I am running Kubernetes version 1.28 and encountering an ErrImagePull error when trying to deploy a pod using a private image registry. Despite specifying the registry to use HTTP in the hosts.toml, the kubelet fails to pull the image, attempting to connect via HTTPS and resulting in connection refused.
Here are the relevant error details:
Failed to pull image "172.16.20.182/k8sdemo/k8s-demo:1.0": failed to pull and unpack image "172.16.20.182/k8sdemo/k8s-demo:1.0": failed to resolve reference "172.16.20.182/k8sdemo/k8s-demo:1.0": failed to do request: Head "https://172.16.20.182/v2/k8sdemo/k8s-demo/manifests/1.0": dial tcp 172.16.20.182:443: connect: connection refused


k8s-demo.yaml configuration:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: k8s-demo
  name: k8s-demo
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: k8s-demo
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: k8s-demo
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: k8s-demo
      containers:
      - name: k8s-demo
        image: 172.16.20.182/k8sdemo/k8s-demo:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources: {}
status: {}

Private registry configuration (/etc/containerd/certs.d/172.16.20.182/hosts.toml):
server = "http://172.16.20.182"
[host."http://172.16.20.182"]
  capabilities = ["pull", "resolve"]
  skip_verify = true
  plain-http = true
  [host."http://172.16.20.182".tls]
    insecure = true
  [host."http://172.16.20.182".header]
    authorization = "Basic YWRtaW46c2luSDW=="

Despite the hosts.toml being configured to use HTTP and skip TLS verification, it seems that Kubernetes is still trying to pull the image via HTTPS. How can I ensure that Kubernetes correctly uses HTTP for pulling images from my private registry?
Using nerdctl for direct image pulling: I also tried pulling the image directly using nerdctl with debug enabled, to isolate the problem to Kubernetes or its configuration. The command used was:
nerdctl --debug=true image pull 172.16.20.182/k8sdemo/k8s-demo:1.0

This command successfully pulled the image from the private registry without any errors, which suggests that the registry, network, and HTTP configuration are functional outside of Kubernetes.
I expected Kubernetes to pull the image from the specified private registry using HTTP as per the configuration in hosts.toml. The pods should have started without any issues related to image pulling. The explicit configuration to use HTTP and to skip TLS verification was supposed to bypass any HTTPS requirements imposed by the default settings or by any previous configurations.

Did you create the secret correctly?
The Docker JSON config would be like:
{
  "auths": {
    "172.16.20.182": {
      "auth": "YWRtaW46c2luSDW=="
    }
  }
}

Which you need to encode in base64 and create a Kubernetes secret to use it from.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: k8s-demo
  namespace: default
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyIxNzIuMTYuMjAuMTgyIjp7ImF1dGgiOiJZV1J0YVc0NmMybHVTRFc9PSJ9fX0=
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson

That should pull the image correctly.
PS. Basic auth is just base64 encoded the user/pass is admin:sinH5

Thank you for your advice! I resolved the issue; it was due to not syncing the configuration files across all Kubernetes cluster nodes. I use containerd, not Docker, which worked fine once everything was synchronized. Thanks again for your help!
